# Uploading multiple image url's to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload multiple images that are in the form of url's to Facebook using the graph api. Below is my code for uploading 1 image. Anyone know how to upload multiple image url's to Facebook with 1 request? Thanks!

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        urlString, @"url",
                        nil
                        ];

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos", albumID];
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:path
                             parameters:@{params : @"file1", params : @"file2"}
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          if (!error) {
                              NSLog(@"success");
                          }
                          else {
                              NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                          }
                      }];
```

Comment: That’s not possible via API.

Answer (score 0):

try this [ios upload image to facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821575/ios-upload-image-to-facebook)
if you want to add multiple images through url then the most easy way is to post a message on facebook which have all the url's in it :) Happy coding :)